# unittest.mock.ANY won't match MagicMock

Tags: python, jenkins, mocking, python-unittest

I have a few unit tests that cover a wrapper class around my database using sqlalchemy:

```
exe_mock = self.database.connection.execute
self.database.select()
exe_mock.assert_called_once_with(ANY)
self.assertIn("name='table.select().where()'", repr(exe_mock.call_args[0][0]))
```

I run the test locally, everything works fine. But Jenkins runs the same test and this happens:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/project-develop/tests/test_persistence.py", line 37, in test_select
    exe_mock.assert_called_once_with(ANY)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.5/unittest/mock.py", line 803, in assert_called_once_with
    return self.assert_called_with(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.5/unittest/mock.py", line 792, in assert_called_with
    raise AssertionError(_error_message()) from cause
AssertionError: Expected call: execute(<ANY>)
Actual call: execute(<MagicMock name='table.select().where()' id='140334112380240'>)
```

Now, this is very awkward. Why wouldn't `ANY` be able to match with `MagicMock`?

**UPDATE 1**

After remotely connecting to the Jenkins worker, I activated the virtualenv por that project and reproduced the error:

```
>>> from unittest.mock import MagicMock, ANY
>>> f = MagicMock()
>>> f(MagicMock())
<MagicMock name='mock()' id='139946030261304'>
>>> f.called
True
>>> 
>>> f.assert_called_once_with(ANY)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.5/unittest/mock.py", line 803, in assert_called_once_with
    return self.assert_called_with(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.5/unittest/mock.py", line 792, in assert_called_with
    raise AssertionError(_error_message()) from cause
AssertionError: Expected call: mock(<ANY>)
Actual call: mock(<MagicMock id='139946030228088'>)
```

**UPDATE 2**

Turns out the problem is not localized in the virtualenv, it is in the python installation.

Running `python34 -c "from unittest.mock import MagicMock, ANY; f = MagicMock(); f(MagicMock()); f.assert_called_once_with(ANY);"` will work gracefully.

Running `python35 -c "from unittest.mock import MagicMock, ANY; f = MagicMock(); f(MagicMock()); f.assert_called_once_with(ANY);"` will raise the exception.

**UPDATE 3**

Using `pdb`, I could see that the failing point is `((ANY,), {}) != call(MagicMock())` that should return `False` but is returning `True`.

Weirdly enough, `((ANY,), {}) == call(MagicMock())` also returns `True`.

Remotely:

```
>>> pdb.run('((ANY,), {}) != c')
> <string>(1)<module>()->None
(Pdb) s
--Return--
> <string>(1)<module>()->None
```

Locally:

```
>>> pdb.run('((ANY,), {}) != c')
> <string>(1)<module>()->None
(Pdb) s
--Call--
> /usr/lib/python3.5/unittest/mock.py(1981)__eq__()
-> def __eq__(self, other):
```

Comment: I'm closing my own question because it seems that the Python installation is just corrupted somehow. I can't reproduce this in other machines.

Comment: Oddly enough, it doesn't match `MagicMock` for me either. Did you find out anything about this problem later? What Python version were you using at when you ran this code?

Comment: @DrunkenMaster I think I was using CPython 3.5. I was unable to solve it, IIRC I just changed to another version or nuked the Jenkins VM and made a new one. From my Update 2 you can see that 3.4 worked, so I probably used it.

Comment: For me, it turned out to be the wrong assumption that `ANY` will much _any_ number of arguments, but it only matches exactly one. 
So `foo(a, b)` and `foo.assert_called_once_with(ANY, ANY)` will pass, but not `foo.assert_called_once_with(ANY)`. Of course this knowledge would have been little help to you, because MagicMock() should be just one argument in  `f(MagicMock())`; so `f.assert_called_once_with(ANY)` should have passed by that rule.